# move_uploaded_file doesn't work right in loop for

Tags: php, loops

My code is:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['creative']['name']['icon']); $i++) {
    $name = mt_rand(0, time());
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['creative']['tmp_name']['icon'] 
    [$i],'creatives/'.$name.'.png');
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['creative']['tmp_name']['image'] 
    [$i],'creatives/'.$name.'.png');
}
```

The problem is that in this code only the last `move_uploaded_file` works and uploads an image.

Can you explain me why the first `move_uploaded_file` does not work?

Comment: When you isolate the `mt_rand(0, time());` and output it what are you seeing?

Comment: mt_rand(0, time()) is just for file's name.

Answer (score -1):

You must set another name for image file.
In your code you set the $name for both icon and image.